# SDWebImage not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, sdwebimage

I'm was developing an app using iOS7 SDK, when I moved to iOS8 SDWebImage stop working properly. If I try this:

```
[imgViewTemp setImageWithURL:urlPhoto completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
             NSlog(@"done");
         }];
```

the completion block simply doesn't get called. Is anybody having the same problem?

Comment: Check their library on Git, if there is no support for iOS 8, then they have not tested it, but you can help them by opening an Issue to tell developers to support iOS 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @3d1d advice I have solved the problem. I posted an issue on GitHub and one of their collaborators helped me.

For those experiencing the same problem:

1.If (like me) you're currently using Cocoa Pods for developing your
    iOS8 project I strongly suggest to remove any reference to
    SDWebImage from your Podfile

2.Run `pod install`

3.Download SDwebImage using

```
git clone https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git --recursive
```

4. Import normally the "UIImageView+WebCache.h" category to your project

That made the trick for me.

Source: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/786

Kudos to **bpoplauschi** for the help.

Comment: Update: SDWebImage v3.7.0 has been released. You can again use the cocoapod. Thanks

Comment: @Claus "UIImageView+WebCache.h" is already present in my project then why call is not coming in the block after success or failure